# 4.1 ANTLR accepts illegal input for palindrome grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4, palindrome

Given the following simple palindrome grammar,
the resulting parser seems to accept any combination
of a's and b's rather than just palindromes.
[well, that was true when I incorrectly specified the start symbol; now I've revised to fix that but still don't get the desired behavior, so I'm adding my exact commands to run as well]
[and revised again, displaying suggested changes and resulting problems.]

```
// test1.g4

grammar test1;

palindrome
    : 'z' entry EOF ;
entry
    : 'a' entry 'a'
    | 'b' entry 'b'
    | 'a' 
    | 'b'
    |
    ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Given this exact test1.g, I then execute the following shell script:

```
#!bash
# script for running ANTLR tests
ANTLR4="java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.1-complete.jar"
$ANTLR4 test1.g4
echo "grammar compiled"
x=/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.1-complete.jar
javac -classpath $x *.java 2>&1
echo "parser compiled"
#java -cp $x:. org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig test1 start -tokens -trace -diagnost
java -cp $x:. org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig test1 palindrome -tokens
```

And then running it on input "aab" gives:

```
aab
[@0,0:0='a',<2>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='a',<2>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='b',<1>,1:2]
[@3,4:3='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
No method for rule palindrome or it has arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I pass `aab` to it, I get the following output:

> line 1:3 no viable alternative at input 'b'

Are you sure you're telling it to start with `entry` instead of `start` now? If you start with `entry`, the generated code literally does not contain a code flow path that will not produce a syntax error for the input `aab`. You could hide the message by overriding the output listener, piping stdout somewhere you can't see, or terminating the process before parsing completes, but the syntax error *will* happen otherwise.

Comment: Ah, of course! ANTLR makes you specify the start symbol 2 different ways, not one. I shouldn't try to think past midnight. Thanks!

Comment: Well, crikey, I still don't get the right behavior and can't see what I've done wrong. I apologize for wasting your time on what is probably some trivial error I can't spot.

Comment: Try renaming the `start` rule to `palindrome` in `test1.g4`. The name is misleading and that will ensure that your script isn't actually starting at the wrong rule.

Comment: Must be some simple mistake somewhere. I'll keep futzing.